# SwiftUI Custom Dropdown in one direction

Tags: swift, drop-down-menu, swiftui

I am trying to make a custom dropdown bar in SwiftUI. It looks something like this:

```
VStack{
   Text("Dropdown").onTapGesture{
      self.expand.toggle()
   }
   if expand {
      Text("Dropdown Item 1")
      Text("Dropdown Item 2")
   }
}
.padding(10)
.background(.green)
.cornerRadius(10)
.animation(.spring())
```

Expand is a `@State var` variable.

The current problem is that when Text("Dropdown") is clicked, the VStack expands both ways. Is there a way to have the VStack only expand downward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might depend on overall layout, but in your provided code snapshot it can be solved by changing alignment guide as shown below in demo

[image: demo]

```
VStack{
    Text("Dropdown").onTapGesture{
        self.expand.toggle()
    }
    if expand {
        Text("Dropdown Item 1")
        Text("Dropdown Item 2")
    }
}
.padding(10)
.background(Color.green)
.cornerRadius(10)
.animation(.spring())
.alignmentGuide(VerticalAlignment.center) { $0[.top] }    // << here !!
```